# Structured data not being picked up on telephone number

Tags: html, schema.org, microdata, google-rich-snippets, structured-data

I have the following snippet of code in a website. When I run this through the Google Structured Data Testing Tool, it doesn’t pick up the phone number. I’m not sure where I’m going wrong:

```html
<div class="telephone-number" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
    <p>Call Us: <a itemprop="telephone" href="tel:07749918143">07749 918 143</a></p>
</div>
```

The error generated by the validator is:

> Node is empty. Double check that this is desired and consider removing.

Can someone tell me where I’m going wrong please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Schema.org’s [`telephone` property](http://schema.org/telephone) expects *Text* as value, not a *URL*.

(There’s a [feature request](https://github.com/schemaorg/schemaorg/issues/188) to change this.)

So you could use something like this:

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
    <p>Call Us: <a href="tel:07749918143"><span itemprop="telephone">07749 918 143</span></a></p>
</div>
```