# Multiple and repeated phone numbers in Microdata

Tags: html, seo, schema.org, phone-number, microdata

I'm creating Microdata for an organisation and was wondering about the correct way to add multiple phone numbers to a site.

This are a few options I've got in mind:

1:

```
<ul itemprop="telephone">
    <li><a href="tel:0123132123">Line 1 0123 132 123</a></li>
    <li><a href="tel:0123546334">Line 2 0123 546 334</a></li>
    <li><a href="tel:01233456">Line 3 01233456</a></li>
</ul>
```

2:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="tel:0123132123" itemprop="telephone"> Line 1 0123 132 123</a></li>
    <li><a href="tel:0123546334" itemprop="telephone">Line 2 0123 546 334</a></li>
    <li><a href="tel:01233456" itemprop="telephone">Line 3 01233456</a></li>
</ul>
```

3:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="tel:0123132123"> Line 1 <span itemprop="telephone">0123 132 123</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="tel:0123546334">Line 2 <span itemprop="telephone">0123 546 334</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="tel:01233456">Line 3 <span itemprop="telephone">01233456</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

Also, if the same number has been repeated on a page, will that cause an error even if they are under the same `itemscope`?

Example:

```
<body itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
    <span itemprop="telephone">01233456</span>
    <!-- data -->
    <!-- data -->

    <span itemprop="telephone">01233456</span>
    <!-- data -->
    <!-- data -->

    <span itemprop="telephone">01233456</span>
</body>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`telephone`](http://schema.org/telephone) property expects Text as value. If you want to follow this advice, you should provide this property on an element that generates a string value in Microdata (e.g. `span`) instead of an element that generates a URL value (e.g., `a`).

And if you want to provide multiple `telephone` values, you have to [repeat the property](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22337572/1591669). Providing multiple properties with the same value is not an error, but also not useful (I’d try to avoid it; simply don’t mark up the repeated telephone numbers in the same item).

So **example 3** is correct.

Note that there is a [feature request to also expect URL values for `telephone`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30735286/1591669). If this happens, your **example 2** would also be in line with Schema.org’s advice.

**Example 1** would represent *one* telephone number (`Line 1 0123 132 123 Line 2 0123 546 334 Line 3 01233456`), so it’s not correct.

Comment: Very well explained. Made me understand it a lot more clearly.

Answer (score 1):

your mentioned options 1,2,3 won't work as they will give error! You have itemprop="telephone" on anchor tags, its not valid markup for schema.

your mentioned example will work, but yes it will give the same number 3 times as shown below in image.

Check yourself on [Google Microdata test tool](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I use this one to add the international Prefix:
`<a href="tel:+15551234567" rel="nofollow"><span content="+15551234567" itemprop="telephone">(555) 1234 - 567</span></a>`
so i can display a human readable format (Like 'Support' insteed of (555) 1234 - 567) and give google the expectedt number with +1 the interational prefix.
I removed in content the `- and ()`this is US specific but you can leaved in. I am from outside.
And if you add [ContactPoint](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/customize/contact-points) it will display fine in the knowledgegraph.